# How can I test RAII?

Tags: rust, raii

I'm currently trying to test some RAII code in Rust, and I'd like to delay dropping a value until a specific line of code.

In C#, GC.KeepAlive prevents an object from being garbage collected until after the call to GC.KeepAlive. The method is essentially a no-op from the perspective of the application, but it guarantees a valid reference to an object until a specific point in the code flow. It's mostly useful for testing.

Is there an idiomatic way to delay dropping a value until a certain point in Rust? I'm trying to test some RAII code, and I'd prefer to use a convention recognizable to another Rust programmer.

For example:

```rust
let foo = some_func();

// Force foo to be deallocated

// This line does something that, if foo were still alive, it would fail the test
some_other_func();
```

Comment: [Box::leak](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) might be an answer, but a more concrete example of what you want, perhaps with a minimal code snippet, would help greatly.

Comment: If you're familiar with RAII, Rust's destructor equivalent is the [Drop](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) trait, which runs `.drop()` at the end of scope. You can use [`mem::drop()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html) to drop something immediately, or [`mem::forget()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.forget.html) to *never* drop it. Its not clear how changing the drop behavior aids in testing though.

Comment: <pedantic>Nothing is ever garbage collected in Rust, so you don't need an annotation for it.</pedantic> The only *sort of* adjacent thing that I can think of is `mem::forget`, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking for. A concrete example would help.

Comment: @kmdreko: I'm trying to test a pub-sub system, where the behavior of the test differs based on when the subscription is dropped. bk2204's answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I don't think this is reopenable without a concrete example, but based on the comments and the (accepted) answer, it would probably be a duplicate of [How to delay destruction of unnamed objects?](/q/39111322/3650362).

Comment: @trentcl: Almost! One of the things I do when I learn a new language is search for things like "How do I do [term in language I know] in [term in language I'm learning]." Often I come across "dupe" SO posts, but my search finds the dupe because the original doesn't have the words I'm searching for. In this case, there aren't any SO posts that have both "GC.KeepAlive" and "std::mem::drop" in them. I'm hoping the next time someone searches for "How do I do GC.KeepAlive in Rust," there's an SO post that points them to std::mem::drop.

Comment: @AndrewRondeau That is exactly why it should be marked as a duplicate: so that people who search for the same keywords you used, in the future, will find the duplicate and be directed to the same (hopefully canonical and up to date) source of information. Questions marked as duplicates are never deleted for this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to drop the object explicitly.  When you call `mem::drop`, the object is moved into that function, and therefore the object must exist in the caller before that point and not after that point.  That signals to other Rust developers that you explicitly wanted destruction at that point.  It doesn't necessarily indicate *why* you wanted destruction there, so you may still need a comment if it's not obvious from context.

For example, if you had a temporary directory and needed to keep it around:

```
extern crate tempfile;

fn do_something() {
    let tempdir = tempfile::TempDir::new();

    // Do some things with your temporary directory.

    std::mem::drop(tempdir);

    // Do some things without your temporary directory.
}
```

Comment: If you removed `drop(tempdir)` from this function, the result is not that `tempdir` might be dropped sooner, as OP's description of `KeepAlive` suggests, but that it would be dropped *later* (when it goes out of scope).

Comment: @trentcl: When drop(tempdir) is removed, the behavior is that the directory is deleted immediately. (It doesn't remain until the end of the scope.) The Rust compiler drops tempdir after the last use, not at the end of the scope.

Comment: @AndrewRondeau You are mistaken. Removing `drop(tempdir)` *and only that line* from this example will cause the directory to not be deleted until it goes out of scope. You are probably thinking of some slightly different code which you haven't shared.

Comment: @trentcl: You're right. I just commented out a drop in one of my tests and it passed. Must have been confused about something I struggled with when trying Rust and WASM.